# Show that $V(XZ - Y^2, YZ - X^3, Z^2 - X^2Y)$ is irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from Problem 2.8 (b) in Fulton's "Algebraic Curves". The hint given asks to show that $Y^3 - X^4, Z^3 - X^5, Z^4 - Y^5 \in I(V)$ and then find a polynomial map from $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{C})$ onto $V$.

I can see how to show that the 3 polynomials are in $I(V)$. But I can't seem to find a parameterization of $V(Y^3 - X^4, Z^3 - X^5, Z^4 - Y^5)$. I assume theres a general way to find parameterizations given this but I don't know of that yet. How do I go about that? Also I can't seem to show that $V(Y^3 - X^4, Z^3 - X^5, Z^4 - Y^5) \subseteq V(XZ - Y^2, YZ - X^3, Z^2 - X^2Y)$, any suggestions about how to show that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a parametrisation $(X,Y,Z)=(t^a,t^b,t^c)$. We must have $a+c=2b$,
$b+c=3a$ and $2c=2a+b$. Therefore $a-b=2b-3a$, so $4a=3b$. Then $(a,b,c)=(3,4,5)$ works. So try $t\mapsto(t^3,t^4,t^5)$

Comment: Yes i did try that, but it didnt seem to work. I cant see how to show that if $X = t^3$ then $Y = t^4$ and $Z = t^5$

Comment: You have $XZ=Y^2$ and $YZ=X^3$. If $XYZ\ne0$ then this gives $X^4=Y^3$, that is $X=t^3$ and $Y=t^4$ for $t=Y/X$. Then $Z=t^5$ drops out. Finally you need to mop up the cases where some of the variables are zero.

Comment: Hmm it does appear to work. I guessed that $X = t^3$ but I see that is not sufficient. What I missed was taking it one step further to get $t = Y/X$.

Comment: Yes, $t$ has to be the "right" cube root of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Put $t=\frac{Y}{X}$, now you can check that $X=t^3$, $Y=t^4$ and $Z=t^5$. This parametrization satisfies the relations given by the ideal.

How can you get this? I tried playing with the relations and dividing by one of the indeterminates to see if I can express all indeterminates in terms of a quotient.

What worked to me, was combining relations 1 and 2 so you get $Y\cdot Y^2 = YZX = X^4$, so $X= (Y/X)^3$. Then the rest are easy $ Z=Y^2/X = Y\cdot t$, so we only need to find $Y$ in terms of $t$, we use the third relation $Y=Z^2/X^2 = \frac{Y^2t^2}{t^6}$ so $Y= t^4$. And finally $Z=t^5$.